# Are there examples of quantization aware neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch

I'm looking for examples of Machine Learning / Neural Networks examples that work with quantized weights, activation functions,.... The simple approach of training with floating point parameters and then quantizing does not give results. I'm working with pytorch now but can use other packages if necessary.

Comment: It does not work?  It is all quantized.  Many learners can work on 16-bit representations.  Gradient-descent has to be performed on the discretized parameters. (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8907458)

Comment: I'm working with much less than 16 bits...here's a survey of methods https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.13630 I'm looking for coded examples

Comment: So, like this one?  https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2018/12/8-bit-precision-training/

Comment: that's the general idea...some starter code would help me get up to speed

Comment: So, like this: https://github.com/MatthieuCourbariaux/8-bit-deep-learning ? Seems to have "QuantizedDenseLayer" in the python code.